# PHP __FILE__ gives wrong location for a moved file

Tags: php

I am using PHP to unpack an update for the PHP application itself. This is done by grabbing a zip file from the update server, unzipping it, and then recursively moving the unzipped files over the files that currently exist for the application.

The problem is the next time I go to use the application, __FILE__ (in at least one of the new files) gives the location in the directory where the zip file was originally unzipped. Since this is not the actual location of the file, I get errors in subsequent require function calls that use the __FILE__ to find the current directory.

The weirdest part: all I have to do is open the file in an editor and resave it (add and delete a space for instance), and PHP will then resolve the file path correctly.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong? It seems like somehow PHP "knows" where the file came from and is getting that information rather than where it is currently located. Resaving the file makes PHP (or maybe the file system) wake up.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the filesystem and operating system in question are.

Comment: Sorry, the operating system is linux ubuntu, and the file system is ext3. The only pertinent code is a reference to __FILE__ to get the directory path in a require statement wrapped in a lot of other useless code. I'll try to get a smaller test example and post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem. I should have guessed it was a caching problem. The issue is that the server is using APC opcode caching. I require this file in its location in the unzip folder location. Since the file already exists in the APC cache (exact same file with same modification date), when it requires it in its new location, it is using the cached file in the APC opcode cache, including its old path!

Seems like a bug that it would mix up the path like that, but the fix is easy. If I reset the opcode cache after moving the files, it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

PHP saves the files in temporary locations with different names. My guess is that the unzipping process creates the files in the temp directory and then it goes to move them and does not find the files.

I might be mistaken and did not understand your question very well but try outputting the files' names and their path and the same in the "moving" operation